# I need help with creating .wsdl file - more than one functions are needed!

Tags: php, javascript, web-services

I'm trying to create a web service and for that purpose I've read a fantastic tutorial found here: [web service tutorial](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2007/07/26/php-web-services.html?page=1). Now, everything works fine, but for the service I'm developing I'll need more than one function defined within the .wsdl file. I tried to add one more function to it and I keep getting error messages. This is how my .wsdl looks like:

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?> 
<definitions name='Catalog' 
  targetNamespace='http://example.org/catalog' 
  xmlns:tns=' http://example.org/catalog ' 
  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' 
  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
  xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' 
  xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' 
  xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'> 

<message name='getCatalogRequest'> 
  <part name='catalogId' type='xsd:string'/> 
</message> 
<message name='getCatalogResponse'> 
  <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/> 
</message> 

<message name='getTestMessageRequest'> 
  <part name='testMessage' type='xsd:string'/> 
</message> 
<message name='getTestMessageResponse'> 
  <part name='resultTestMessage' type='xsd:string'/> 
</message> 


<portType name='CatalogPortType'> 
  <operation name='getCatalogEntry'> 
    <input message='tns:getCatalogRequest'/> 
    <output message='tns:getCatalogResponse'/> 
  </operation> 
  <operation name='getTestMessage'> 
    <input message='tns:getTestMessageRequest'/> 
    <output message='tns:getTestMessageResponse'/> 
  </operation> 
</portType> 



<binding name='CatalogBinding' type='tns:CatalogPortType'> 
  <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/> 

  <operation name='getCatalogEntry'> 
    <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-catalog#getCatalogEntry'/> 
    <input> 
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/> 
    </input> 
    <output> 
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/> 
    </output> 
  </operation>

  <operation name='getTestMessage'> 
    <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-catalog#getTestMessage'/> 
    <input> 
      <soap:body use='literal'/> 
    </input> 
    <output> 
      <soap:body use='literal'/> 
    </output> 
  </operation> 
</binding> 

<service name='CatalogService'> 
  <port name='CatalogPort' binding='CatalogBinding'> 
    <soap:address location='http://www.thevinylfactory.com.php5-8.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/ws/soap-server.php'/> 
  </port> 
</service>

</definitions>
```

my soap-server.php

```
<?php
function getCatalogEntry($catalogId) { 
  if($catalogId=='catalog1')
          return "<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Catalog</TITLE>
 </HEAD
 <BODY>
<p> </p>
 <table border>
<tr><th>CatalogId</th>
<th>Journal</th><th>Section
</th><th>Edition</th><th>
Title</th><th>Author</th>
</tr><tr><td>catalog1</td>
<td>IBM developerWorks</td><td>
XML</td><td>October 2005</td>
<td>JAXP validation</td>
<td>Brett McLaughlin</td></tr>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>";
  elseif ($catalogId='catalog2')
          return "<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Catalog</TITLE>
 </HEAD
 <BODY>
<p> </p>
 <table border>

<tr><th>CatalogId</th><th>
Journal</th><th>Section</th>
<th>Edition</th><th>Title
</th><th>Author
</th></tr><tr><td>catalog1
</td><td>IBM developerWorks</td>
<td>XML</td><td>July 2006</td>
<td>The Java XPath API
</td><td>Elliotte Harold</td>
</tr>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>";
}

function getTestMessage($testMessage)
{
    return $testMessage."dsa";

}

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 
$server = new SoapServer("catalog.wsdl"); 
$server->addFunction(array("getCatalogEntry", "getTestMessage")); 
$server->handle(); 


?>
```

my soap-client.php

```
<?php  
  $client = new SoapClient("catalog.wsdl");
  $catalogId = 'catalog2';
  $testMessage = "Some Message";
  $response = $client->getCatalogEntry($catalogId);
  $response2 = $client->getTestMessage($testMessage);

  echo $response;
  echo "<br /><br />";
  echo $response2;
?>
```

and the error I'm getting:

```
[31-Jan-2011 04:30:29] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getTestMessage") is not a valid method for this service in /mnt/stor2-wc2-dfw1/441352/www.thevinylfactory.com/web/content/ws/soap-client.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('getTestMessage', Array)
#1 /mnt/stor2-wc2-dfw1/441352/www.thevinylfactory.com/web/content/ws/soap-client.php(6): SoapClient->getTestMessage('Some Message')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /mnt/stor2-wc2-dfw1/441352/www.thevinylfactory.com/web/content/ws/soap-client.php on line 6
```

Can some please help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've found a solution - it seems that wsdl file was caching. I'm posting this in case someone else will experience similar issue. All you have to do is to add this line in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 0
```

Comment: I have installed XAMPP, where can i find the .htaccess file